# Where to download SonarQube Runner .9?

Tags: sonarqube

Where can I download SonarQube Runner version .9? We are planning on updating SonarQube, but until then I need the older version.

Comment: If you goto http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ and hit the "Show all versions" link you will see that there is no support for a pre 1.x version.  You may be out of luck.  If you find someone out there saying you can download it from them, I would be careful..  BTW. Stack Overflow is for programming questions so you question will most likely get closed by the community..

Comment: How old a version of the platform are you using?

Comment: @G. Ann - SonarSource Team +1 for SonarSource/SonarQube having somebody on SO.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewD. Most of us are to some degree tho. Just do a Users search for "SonarSource" :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried searching SonarQube website?  Here is a link to their downloads page [SonarQube Downloads](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)